# How to send mail with scraped data?

Tags: python, email, scrapy, pipeline

How to send email with specific scraped data after spider ends in Scrapy.

I'm trying to send some item data with multiple lines after the end of a spider, but i'm only receiving one line. I think i have to do some iteration but i can't make it work.

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class ScrapeadorItem(scrapy.Item):
    Nro = scrapy.Field()
    SITUACION = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.mail import MailSender

mailer = MailSender(mailfrom="*@gmail.com", smtpuser="*@gmail.com", smtphost="smtp.gmail.com", smtpport=587, smtppass="*")

class ScrapeadorPipeline:
    
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        contenidomail = ""            
        if adapter.get('SITUACION') == "DESCARGADO":
            contenidomail = contenidomail + "\n" + str(adapter.get('Nro')) + " " + adapter.get('SITUACION') + "\n"
            self.contenidomail = contenidomail
    
        return item
    
    def close_spider(self, item):
        mailer.send(to=["*@msn.com"], subject="Reporte", body=self.contenidomail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concatenate each item to `self.contenidomail`, not the local `contenidomail` variable (which you just initialized to be empty).

```
class ScrapeadorPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.contenidomail = ''
    
    def process_item(self, item, spider): 
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter.get('SITUACION') == "DESCARGADO":
            self.contenidomail += str(adapter.get('Nro')) + " " + adapter.get('SITUACION') + "\n"    
        return item
    
    def close_spider(self, item):
        mailer.send(to=["*@msn.com"], subject="Reporte", body=self.contenidomail)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm getting this error with it: AttributeError: 'ScrapeadorPipeline' object has no attribute 'contenidomail'

Comment: @Harker `__init__` should be outside of `process_item` function. In other words, it should be a method of `ScrapeadorPipeline` class.